# assistance with scripting list of users

Tags: linux, shell-script, aix

I'm new to scripting, so far I've created this:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo List of users in PRD 

echo $(date)

cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1,$3,$5}' | sort | \
while read username uid gecos
do
echo "${username}:${uid}:${gecos}"
done
) > `hostname`_userlogins.txt
mailx -s file xxxxxx@unix.com < `hostname`_userlogins.txt
```

This gives a list of all users. I have another file (called `ignore.txt`) which has list of users to be excluded before sending the email out.

How do I link the list with `ignore.txt` to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` to filter out usernames:

```
grep -wvf ignore.txt /etc/passwd | awk ...
```

`grep` is used to search for patterns usually, but with `-v` can be used to negate the search, and thus for filtering. The matches can be a bit broad (for example, `joe` will filter out `joe` and `joey`), so use `-w` to restrict its effect to whole-word matches.

Other suggestions:

- `awk` can be told to print with colons, saving you the trouble of the loop:

  ```
  grep -wvf ignore.txt /etc/passwd | awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $1, $2, $3}'
  ```
- `echo $(date)` is pointless. Just use `date`.
- Use `tee` to write to a file and again to the pipe:

  ```
  ) | tee "$(hostname)"_userlogins.txt | mail ...
  ```

Overall, the script can be simplified to:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo List of users in PRD 

date

grep -wvf ignore.txt /etc/passwd | awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $1,$3,$5}' | sort 
) | tee "$(hostname)"_userlogins.txt |
mailx -s file xxxxxx@unix.com
```

Comment: i tried above,i didnt get any output other than list of users in Prd and date,am i missing something?

Comment: @ZairaZareena does your `ignore.txt` contain a blank line?

Comment: its just has username like

Comment: it worked like a charm thank you only problem i have is there is no gap between them (between list of prd, date and the username list)

Comment: @ZairaZareena  add an `echo` command wherever you need a gap - without any arguments,`echo` just prints a blank line.

Comment: it worked nice.Is it how it behaves when you usually get an email through scripting subject comes out to be "file"

Comment: how do i give you a star rating here .or medal here.You been very helpful

Comment: @ZairaZareena Thanks. You have used `-s file` - the `-s` option sets the subject. If you found the answer useful, you can click the tick next to it to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: my bad thank you for your help , can i add you here

Comment: now i need to find a way to run this on 5 servers ,wondering if i can run this on one server and it goes and runs on other servers.. or i have to set a cron job on each server to run this

Comment: For that, I suppose you should ask a new question.